# Inserting columns in Excel VBA (looped)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a code that will run through specific row and if it finds cell with value "1" it adds column next to it and moves on.

I stumbled upon a problem, at this point when my macro finds cell with value 1 it starts adding infinite numbers of columns instead of one and moving to the next cell. Can you help me?

```
Sub makro()

Set zakres = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
For Each Cell In zakres.Rows(3).Cells
If Cell.Value = 1 Then
Cell.EntireColumn.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End If

Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you want to insert the Column? Before or after? Btw, the reason why it adds infinite column is that once you insert a column, the cell you just tested becomes the currently tested cell again. So it will insert column again and then the loop repeats all over again moving your cell with 1 to the furthest column.

Comment: I would like to insert column to the right. If it helps, if we choose 6 as a value it can be inserted to the left. What can we do to resolve this problem when currently tested cell moves and its tested again and again... ?

Comment: Yeah, you got it right. I already posted a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which will insert columns before any cell with ***1*** in it.

**Edit1:** Iterate on Row3 only

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, ir As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With Activesheet
        Set r = .Range("A3", .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With
    For i = r.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If r.Cells(i).Value = 1 Then r.Cells(i).EntireColumn.Insert xlToRight
    Next
End Sub
```

We used the classic *For Loop* instead of *For Each*.
This way we can easily loop backwards. HTH.

Comment: Thanks, it kinda works. There is still something wrong with using "Used range". When I selected range A1:AA3 it worked. When using UsedRAnge it goes crazy. I guess because there is more data in the sheet. When I tried to changed it to Row(3) it didn't work. How else we can set range in this particular code?

Comment: @user3740972 Where exactly is your data? What row? You just have to be explicit on that and it will work. :) Yeah, you are right about UsedRange, it's kinda messy often.

Comment: Those values that we need to insert new columns are in row 3 only.

Comment: L42, I really get confused by those ranges, objects and stuff. I need to read up on that a little bit more ;) Thanks for your help mate.